# Troubles to start the right tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have troubles to start the right tomcat. 
I installed tomkat 8 (with servlet-api 3.1) in Eclipse. Window-Preference-Server-Runtime Invirements- Add- Apache Tomcat v8.0 - directory (C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28) - Finish
But Eclipse runs a tomcat with servlet-api 2.x. 
System.out.println(getServletContext().getMajorVersion()) show 2.
How to start tomcat which getServletContext().getMajorVersion() must be 3 ?

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<!-- SERVLET -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletMenu</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/menu.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletMenu</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- SERVLET -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletList</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/list.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletList</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/list.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- SERVLET -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletImport</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/import.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletImport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/import.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- SERVLET -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Menu</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.training.Menu</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<!-- SERVLET MAPPING -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Menu</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/menu</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- SERVLET -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>List</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.training.ListDisplay</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<!-- SERVLET MAPPING -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>List</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/list.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- SERVLET -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Import</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.training.Import</servlet-class>

</servlet>
<!-- SERVLET MAPPING -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Import</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/import</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>menu.jsp</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Please show us the content of web.xml

Comment: Well, you're using dtd for version 2.3, how else do you expect to use version 3 then?

Comment: What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a header for Servlets 3.1 like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <!-- proper configuration of your app -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: nothing changed . In Eclipse At start of tomcat  write INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Comment: Tomcat 8 doesn't support servlet 3. Probably you have not configured tomcat 8 in your eclipse installation. Please follow [this guide](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/InstallTomcat/InstallTomcat.html) and then make sure your application is set to run on that tomcat explicitly by following [this guide](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjtargetserver.html).